# May-McClure "A reduction of Segal conjecture"

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am looking for a digitalized version of paper by J.P. May and J. McClure *A reduction of Segal conjecture*, as I need it to understand some lemma from Kuhn's *Tate Cohomology and Periodic Localization of Polynomial Functors*. The paper was published in *Current Trends in Algebraic Topology*, Canadian Mathematical Society Conference Proceedings, 1982.

I hope this is not breach of any rules - given the current situation, I cannot go to University's library and check the hard copy, and I cannot find any version of this article on the internet. Any help would be highly appreciated!

(If nobody has an access to a digitalized version, could sbdy quote what Corollary 4 is saying?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it on professor May's web site at http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/42.pdf

<sub>Since this link might disappear, it is also archived at the [Wayback Machine.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120608135619/http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/42.pdf)</sub>

Comment: It works, thanks!